# set JButton size in gridLayout

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton

How to set the size of jbutton in gridlayout? otherwise the button size have lot of width and its not listening setSize or setBounds or setPreferedSize.

```
    addBut = new JButton("Add");

    addBut.addActionListener(this);
    deleteBut = new JButton("Delete");
    deleteBut.addActionListener(this);
    selectionPanel = new JPanel();
    selectionPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
    TitledBorder selectionBorder = new TitledBorder("Options");
    selectionBorder.setTitleColor(Color.BLUE);
    selectionPanel.setBorder(selectionBorder);
    selectionPanel.add(new JLabel("Department Name"));
    selectionPanel.add(new JTextField(deptName));
    selectionPanel.add(addBut);
    selectionPanel.add(deleteBut);

    selectionPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900,100));
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) & ASCII art of the GUI in 'smallest' and 'larger' size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe setting GridLayout(2,2) will override size changes made to the panels. To be more precise, use GridBagConStraints;

```
private JTextField field1 = new JTextField();
private JButton addBtn = new JButton("Save: ");

 public void addComponents(Container pane) {
        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
// Components
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.weightx = .01;
    c.weighty = .2;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    pane.add(field1, c);

        c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.weightx = .01;
    c.weighty = .2;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    pane.add(addBtn, c);
}
public MainView()  {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("NAME");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Set up the content pane.
        addComponents(frame.getContentPane());

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(400, 125);
        frame.setLocation(400, 300);
    }
```

Comment: if i set constraints, everything goes to different size, could you please update ur code with guess constraints, i am looking for label and textfiled in first line and 2 buttons in next line. Thank you