# how to set Constraints to GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout

I am looking for a way to add jlabel and jtextfield on first line and 2 jbuttons on second line and in the centre of the jpanel. but how to set the constraints using gridbaglayout?

```
    selectionPanel.add(new JLabel("Department Name"));
    selectionPanel.add(new JTextField(deptName));
    selectionPanel.add(addBut);
    selectionPanel.add(deleteBut);
```

Comment: See [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for working examples. You also have an example in your other posting (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388870/set-jbutton-size-in-gridlayout). Put some effort into it and post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) if you have a problem. Don't expect us to write the code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll need to set layout to `GridBagLayout`.

Then you'll need to create new `GridBagConstraints` for each component (this way, you'll not get values from the last component on the next you're creating).

In the `add()` method, you'll pass the component and constraints.

```
setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout())
java.awt.GridBagConstraints constraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
constraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;
constraints.weighty = 0.1;
constraints.weightx = 0.3;
javax.swing.JButton unlockButton = new javax.swing.JButton("jbutton text");
add(unlockButton, constraints);
```

Answer (score 2):

You create a GridBagContraints object, set its properties appropriately, and pass the constraints object as the 2nd parameter to your panel's add(...) method.

See: [How To Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)